# How does Stack Overflow define interesting questions on the home page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, feed, homepage, interesting-page

There is [interesting questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) on the home page.  How does Stack Overflow define what is interesting to me?

Comment: I am a new user and not familiar with how to ask a question. I re-edited the question.Could you answer it?

Comment: Your revised question is answered here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ (unless SE tweaked their algorithm recently, which I suspect they did).

Comment: Things have changed enough that this really isn't  duplicate any longer. It's also perfectly on-topic here. I'll see about getting this answered.

Comment: @Tim I disagree. In such case we should simply update the original, not starting a new question. No?

Comment: @TimPost I'd love to hear about the changes; my impression is that the "recent" factor is now emphasized more than "unanswered". But I agree with Shadow in that the old post needs an update; having two posts  with different information will be confusing.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat The definition of interesting tab is that questions that may be of interest to you  based on your history and preference tags. But I didn't see the history is mentioned in the blog. How does the history work?

Comment: Top 40 scoring tags reflect the history of answering.